# LaTex Blockarray Weird Placement of Brackets

Tags: matrices, brackets, block, border

I'm unfamiliar with LaTex terms, so please excuse my vocabulary. I have this in my exam latex file in two different places (copied and pasted), however I get different results.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace, gensymb, graphicx, float, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{kbordermatrix,blkarray, array, booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\singlespacing

\begin{document} 
\begin{questions}
\question Write the solution that can be read from each simplex tableau.
\[
\begin{blockarray}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & z & \\ [1 ex]
\begin{block}{[@{}cccccc|c@{}]}
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 3 &  \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 & \\ 
\cline{1-7} 
& & & & & & & \\ [-2 ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 7 &\\ 
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\newpage
\question Pivot once as indicated in the simplex tableau. Then read the       solution from the result. Be sure to support your answer by writing each row operation used. 
\begin{parts}
\part 
\[
\begin{blockarray}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & z & \\ [1 ex]
\begin{block}{[@{}ccccccc|c@{}]}
\circled{1} & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 50 &  \\ 
2 & 6 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 100 & \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 150 \\ 
\cline{1-8} 
& & & & & & & & \\ [-2 ex]
-2 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\\ 
\end{block}
\end{blockarray} \quad
\]
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\newpage
\begin{questions}
\question The initial simplex tableau is: \\
\[
\begin{blockarray}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & z & \\ [1 ex]
\begin{block}{[@{}cccccc|c@{}]}
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 3 &  \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 & \\ 
\cline{1-7} 
& & & & & & & \\ [-2 ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 7 &\\ 
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The first one is how I want it to look:

[image]

However, when it is copied and pasted into a different part of the document, I get this:

[image]

Same code in a \question, but different results. Any idea why?

Update: Here is the rest of the code. The matrix looks normal when I delete 2a).

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You will need to produce a complete document demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have seven columns, but also seven `&` characters; remove the trailing `&`'s.

```
\[
\begin{blockarray}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & z \\ [1 ex]
\begin{block}{[@{}cccccc|c@{}]}
1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 \\
\cline{1-7}
& & & & & & \\ [-2 ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 7\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

[image]